# Calling a program which could have 2 different names

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that uses 'get-iplayer' and will be used on differing distros. On debian it is in '/usr/bin/get-iplayer', but on centos, for example, it is in '/usr/bin/get_iplayer'.

I've been able to check if its even installed with -

```
if [[ -f "/usr/bin/get-iplayer" ]] || [[ -f "/usr/bin/get_iplayer" ]]
then
    echo ;
else
    echo "$(tput setaf 1) $(tput setab 7) Error: 'get-iplayer' or 'get_iplayer' is not     installed. Please install it. $(tput sgr 0)"
fi
```

How then can I call it when it could be known by two different names please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if [[ -x "/usr/bin/get-iplayer" ]]
then player="/usr/bin/get-iplayer"
elif [[ -x "/usr/bin/get_iplayer" ]]
then player="/usr/bin/get_iplayer"
else echo "$0: error: neither get-iplayer nor get_iplayer is installed in /usr/bin" >&2
     exit 1
fi

# Run it
"$player" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Test both paths/names, then set an alias within your script that points to the one that was found. Use that alias for the remainder of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to Jonathan Leffler's answer, but using a shell function instead of parameter expansion:

```
get_iplayer () {
    if [[ -x "/usr/bin/get-iplayer" ]]
    then /usr/bin/get-iplayer "$@"
    elif [[ -x "/usr/bin/get_iplayer" ]]
    then /usr/bin/get_iplayer "$@"
    else echo "$0: error: neither get-iplayer nor get_iplayer is installed in /usr/bin" >&2
    exit 1
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debian actually has both `get-iplayer` and `get_iplayer`. `get_iplayer` is the real name of the script. Debian adds the symlink `get-iplayer` because the hyphenated name is in line with their package naming convention (and thus the name of the package). You should be able to use `get_iplayer` on any system, as this is the upstream canonical name and it would be bad practice to alter it.